# ProceedingJoinPoint.proceed() fails with ClassCastException when run on new thread

Tags: android, aop, aspectj

I'm setting up and `@Around` aspect to run a method on a background thread, it looks like this

```
@Aspect
public class ThreadAspect {    
    @Around("call(@Background void *(..))")
    public void runInBackground(final ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        new Thread(new JPRunner(jp)).start();
    }

    private static class JPRunner implements Runnable {
        ...
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                jp.proceed();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Log.e("TEST", "ThreadAspect", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I applied the `@Background` annotation on a method that takes a `String` but it fails with a `ClassCastException` on the line with `jp.proceed()`

```
E/TEST    (20943): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint
```

Funnily enough, if I did not use a thread, the call seems to make it through just fine. How can I make it run on a thread?

If it matters, I'm using aspectj on android with [this plugin](https://github.com/leolin310148/GradleAndroidAspectJPlugin).

**EDIT:** this is the failing code

```
// Background.java
package com.github.larvyde.ex.aspect;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Background {}

// MainActivity.java
package com.github.larvyde.ex.aspect;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
        super.onCreate(saved);

        Log.v("TEST", "calling runInBackground");
        runInBackground("run #1");
        Log.v("TEST", "calling runInBackground again");
        runInBackground("run #2");
    }

    @Background
    public void runInBackground(String str) {
        Log.v("TEST", str);
    }
}

// ThreadAspect.java
package com.github.larvyde.ex.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import android.util.Log;

@Aspect
public class ThreadAspect {
    @Around("call(@Background void *(..))")
    public void runInBackground(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        new Thread(new JPRunner(jp)).start();
    }

    private static class JPRunner implements Runnable {
        private final ProceedingJoinPoint jp;

        public JPRunner(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
            this.jp = jp;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                jp.proceed();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Log.e("TEST", "ThreadAspect", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the logs

```
$ adb logcat | egrep 'TEST|AndroidRuntime'
V/TEST    (21315): calling runInBackground
V/TEST    (21315): calling runInBackground again
E/TEST    (21315): ThreadAspect
E/TEST    (21315): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint
E/TEST    (21315):  at com.github.larvyde.ex.aspect.MainActivity$AjcClosure1.run(MainActivity.java:1)
E/TEST    (21315):  at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
E/TEST    (21315):  at com.github.larvyde.ex.aspect.ThreadAspect$JPRunner.run(ThreadAspect.java:25)
E/TEST    (21315):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/TEST    (21315): ThreadAspect
E/TEST    (21315): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint
E/TEST    (21315):  at com.github.larvyde.ex.aspect.MainActivity$AjcClosure3.run(MainActivity.java:1)
E/TEST    (21315):  at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
E/TEST    (21315):  at com.github.larvyde.ex.aspect.ThreadAspect$JPRunner.run(ThreadAspect.java:25)
E/TEST    (21315):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this works nicely, maybe your actual code is different from the one you posted here or you omitted som important information. Look at my stand-alone example:

**Marker annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Background {}
```

**Driver application:**

As you can see, one method is marked by the annotation and another one is not.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Application {
    static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    public static void foreground() {
        System.out.println(
            dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) +
            " - synchronous call"
        );
    }

    @Background
    public static void background() {
        System.out.println(
            dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) +
            " - asynchronous call"
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foreground();
        background();
        foreground();
        background();
    }
}
```

**Console output without AspectJ:**

```
18:21:09 - synchronous call
18:21:09 - asynchronous call
18:21:09 - synchronous call
18:21:09 - asynchronous call
```

As you can see, the methods are logged in the order in which they are called and all with the same timestamp.

**Aspect running marked methods asynchronously in their own threads:**

This is pretty much your aspect code, but I inserted a waiting time of 2 seconds in order to demonstrate the `@Background` effect.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class ThreadAspect {
    @Around("call(@de.scrum_master.app.Background void *(..))")
    public void runInBackground(final ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        new Thread(new JPRunner(jp)).start();
    }

    private static class JPRunner implements Runnable {
        ProceedingJoinPoint jp;
        JPRunner(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) { this.jp = jp; }

        @Override public void run() {
            try { Thread.sleep(2000); jp.proceed(); }
            catch (Throwable e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
}
```

**Console output with AspectJ:**

```
18:23:21 - synchronous call
18:23:21 - synchronous call
18:23:23 - asynchronous call
18:23:23 - asynchronous call
```

As you can see here, both asynchronous calls (backgound tasks) are printed 2 seconds after the synchronous ones.

Comment: Nope, it's pretty much copy-pasted from my code. Hmm, I see you tested it on regular java, so I guess it might be an issue with the android aspectj plugin I'm using...

Comment: I do not think so. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in order to make the problem reproduceable and prove the opposite. If I can reproduce it, I can help you.

Comment: Does your exact code run on a desktop PC outside Android when compiled in a normal Eclipse AspectJ project? You need to replace the Android log call with `System.out.println(..)` or another logging framework, though.

Comment: One more question: Which Java language level and which AspectJ version do you use?